# Most recent date associated with a number greater than 6

Tags: arrays, excel

I am using excel, and have two columns laid out like so:

Column A   - This contains dates

Column B   - This contains numbers

I am using an array formula to scan column B to find all occurrences of numbers > 6 and then checking if their is a match or no match.

Then where there is a match I am checking column A for the most recent date which corresponds to the value in column b.

I am doing this using the following array formula:

```
{=IF(COUNTIF(B:B,">6")=0,"No Match",MAX(IF(B:B=">6",A:A)))}
```

I am then counting the number of days from today in which this value has occurred.

```
=IFERROR(TODAY()-M1,0)
```

I am getting an error message saying there is an error in my formula for the following formula

```
{=IF(COUNTIF(B:B,">6")=0,"No Match",MAX(IF(B:B=">6",A:A)))}
```

Comment: The `IF(B:B=">6",A:A)` section should be `IF(B:B>6, A:A)`. An IF doesn't work the same as the [COUNTIF function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34) and the countif would be better as `COUNTIF(B:B,">"&6)=0` but it will work the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use a standard non-array formula for this by putting the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) to work with the [MAX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/max-function-f7bec1eb-9c66-489a-9166-51d2c9d19333).

```
=MAX(INDEX($A:$A*($B:$B>6), , ))
```

That will be returned as a date serial number like *42,125*. You will have to format it as a date.